# Как разобрать по составу  это предложение?

Tags: члены-предложения

Всё те ж у вас и люди,и собаки..

Answer (score 1):

Всё те ж у вас и люди,и собаки.Подлежащее-и люди, и собаки, сказуемое -всё те ж,
где? у вас - обстоятельство, с оттенком дополнения( у кого?-у вас)

Answer (score 0):

Людмила права. 
И люди, и собаки (каковы?) всё те же.